# mobaxterm new installation with old license

Tags: mobaxterm

I have an old version of mobaxterm 10.4 pro with license but not renewed
Something happened on my windows pc and moba is not usable anymore
I still have my license from 10.4
I can find v10.4 personnal edition but can not apply the license ?
is it possible to download somewhere 10.4 pro and enter my old license again ?
best regards, Guy